# Click on a specific item on a list with similar ngcontent classname but has a span unique text using Protractor typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I need help on creating a protractor typescript code, how do i click this specific item on a list? it has _ngcontent that is similar from others and but has specific span text, does anyone have an idea how to do this? code on the site is:

```
<div _ngcontent-c3  class="ListTreeNode addTreeNode ng-star-inserted" style="padding-left: 0px;"> ... </div>
<div _ngcontent-c3  class="ListTreeNode addTreeNode ng-star-inserted" style="padding-left: 0px;">
     <div _ngcontent-c3  class="nodeItemlist net-body-2">
         <!----><!---->
             <fa-icon _ngcontent-c3   class="ng-fa-icon ng-star-inserted">...</fa-icon>
              <!----><!---->
              <span _ngcontent-c3="">Driver Items</span>
              <!---->
        </div>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c3  class="ListTreeNode addTreeNode ng-star-inserted" style="padding-left: 0px;"> ... </div>
```

i've tried the following below, i can't seem to make it work...

```
clickditem = element(by.xpath('//span[@class=".nodeItemlist.net-body-2"][text()="Driver Items"]'));
clickditem = element(by.cssContainingText('.nodeItemlist.net-body-2','Driver Items'));
clickditem = element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-fa-icon.ng-star-inserted','Driver Items'));
```

them performed...

```
clickditem.click();
```

none of these seem to work, and error says: Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath..... or by.cssContainingText(....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
clickditem = element.all(by.cssContainingText('div.nodeItemlist.net-body-2','Driver Items')).get(0);
```

Comment: the selectedList will only appear if it was clicked, if not clicked selectedList does not appeared. if i only add

    element(by.cssContainingText('div.nodeItemlist.net-body-2','Driver Items'));

a warning will appear saying 
W/element - more than one element found for locator by.cssContainingText('div.nodeItemlist.net-body-2','Driver Items') - the first result will be used

Comment: i think warning is saying that there are other dom element with same class and containingText 'Driver Items'

Comment: yup your correct, there are more than other elements with same class and containingtext"Driver Items". But it seems to partially worked since it is the correct first occurrence was executed.                                                                                                           


    clickditem = element(by.cssContainingText('div.nodeItemlist.net-body-2','Driver Items'));

Comment: if you have more than one element for same locator you can use element.all().get(0).see edited answer

Comment: that got it right. thanks, i does not show any warnings now.

Answer (score 0):

```
clickditem = element(by.cssContainingText('div.odeItemlist.net-body-2>span','Driver Items')).first();
```

try the above one. Hope it helps you